# asp.net MVC routeengine doesn't kick in

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm having a bit of a weird problem.
I programmed a asp.net mvc app and runned locally at http://localhost:1234/ it works fine.
i have a route for /employee and this route kicks in.
But when i move it to my webserver at http://myapp.mydomain.nl (it is at a subdomain 'myapp') the /employee route doesn't kick in (i get a 404). 
i have installed the RouteDebug.RouteDebugger component and normally it shows you the yellow and white page to show you which route kicks in, and if you type an invalid uri you see that no route kicks in. But now it doesn't show me this page, but just a 404, so it looks that the mvc doesn't 'kick in' when i navigate to http://myapp.mydomain.nl/employee, but my server treats my request as a normal request so it loos for the nonexisting folder 'employee'.

It is on a server that has not the mvc framework installed so i manually copied the System.Web.Mvc.dll to the bin folder.

Michel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need ASP.NET MVC installed and also setup the wildcard mappings to be able to view MVC routes properly (if using IIS5/6).

Here's a link to setting up ASP.NET MVC with IIS 5 and 6.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2007/12/15/using-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5.aspx
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: problem is that i can't edit IIS setting because my site is hosted at an ISP.